# import MYD file into MySQL database

Tags: mysql, import

I have the following problem. I have a large *.myd* backup file which I need to restore. I tried to import it via phpmyadmin and I got syntax errors. As far as I understood it's a binary file and it should 'work' if I put it into the db directory, but it doesn't show up in the database, even when I restart the MySQL server. Any tips how can I import it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.myd` file alone is not a backup. It's a copy of MyISAM data for a table, but it's missing the *metadata* that's stored in the corresponding `.FRM` file.

You can probably fake-restore your `.myd` file by using `CREATE TABLE` to recreate the original table that your data file was associated with. Then shut down `mysqld`, move your `.myd` file into place, and restart `mysqld`. Not that you need to use the exact same `CREATE TABLE` statement for the column names, positions, and data types for this to work. If you don't remember what those were, you're SOL.

In the future, use a tool like `mysqldump` or `mydumper` or Percona XtraBackup to back up databases. Don't just use `cp` without understanding more about MySQL storage engines.